# How to create notification circle with number in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, drawable, android-drawable

I need to create a circle with number. But the problem is that some numbers is not in center, for example 1 stayed right from center.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <corners android:radius="18dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
</shape>
```

This Drawable is background of TextView

Comment: Can you please show Drawable you created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use attribute

`android:includeFontPadding="false"`

```
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:background="@drawable/test"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="1"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Create file xml drawable file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        >
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#0288D1" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#FFd200"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create a file `round.xml` in `drawable`**

Set this as backgroundResourse for your `textview`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" android:useLevel="true"
    android:dither="true">
    <solid
        android:color="@android:color/white"/>
    <stroke
        android:color="@color/switcher_grey"
        android:width="@dimen/_1ssp"/>
</shape>
```